# solving repetitive html in word press template

Tags: php, html, wordpress, loops

I would like some help In creating a loop for my WP template.

I have the same div block repeated a few times, the class numbers are different and that's about it.

based of the sample blocks bellow can someone give me a example of how i could wrap this in a loop and change the class numbers ?

**code block**

If you see bellow some of the class names just differ with the number

```
  <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php the_field('section_3_image_1') ?>"
                 alt="<?php the_field('section_3_image_1_alt') ?>">
            <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php the_field('text_one', false, false) ?></h3>
            <p class="pb-5">
                <a href="<?php the_field('link_1'); ?>"
                   title="<?php the_field('title_1'); ?>"
                   class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
                    <?php the_field('link_text'); ?>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php the_field('section_3_image_2') ?>"
                 alt="<?php the_field('section_3_image_2_alt') ?>">
            <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php the_field('text_two', false, false) ?></h3>
            <p class="pb-5">
                <a href="<?php the_field('link_2'); ?>"
                   title="<?php the_field('title_2'); ?>"
                   class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
                    <?php the_field('link_text'); ?>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
            <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php the_field('section_3_image_3') ?>"
                 alt="<?php the_field('section_3_image_3_alt') ?>">
            <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php the_field('text_3', false, false) ?></h3>
            <p class="pb-5">
                <a href="<?php the_field('link_3'); ?>"
                   title="<?php the_field('title_3'); ?>"
                   class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
                    <?php the_field('link_text'); ?>
                </a>
            </p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do with this code:

```
<?pho for($i = 0; $i < YOUR_MAX_VALUE; $i++): ?>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
        <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php the_field('section_3_image_' . ($i+1)) ?>"
             alt="<?php the_field('section_3_image_' . ($i+1) . '_alt') ?>">
        <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php the_field('text_one', false, false) ?></h3>
        <p class="pb-5">
            <a href="<?php the_field('link_' . ($i+1)); ?>"
               title="<?php the_field('title_' . ($i+1)); ?>"
               class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
                <?php the_field('link_text'); ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

Remember to set `YOUR_MAX_VALUE` to the value you need.

Comment: your the man, simple and easy. let me try this on my local then accept answer. thank you

Comment: Perfect, your the original the rest just copy you so thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

```
<?pho $i=1; if( have_rows('parent_field') ):
while ( have_rows('parent_field') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
        <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php the_field('section_3_image_' . $i) ?>"
             alt="<?php echo get_field('section_3_image_' . $i . '_alt') ?>">
        <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php echo get_field('text_one', false, false) ?></h3>
        <p class="pb-5">
            <a href="<?php echo get_field('link_' . $i); ?>"
               title="<?php echo get_field('title_' . $i); ?>"
               class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
                <?php echo get_field('link_text'); ?>
            </a>
        </p>
    </div>
<?php $i++; endwhile; endif; ?>
```

if you are working with while loop this will work fine.

This ACF field data and your while will work fine as this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are working with for loop this will work fine.

```
<?pho for($i = 0; $i < YOUR_VALUE.length; $i++): ?>
    <div class="col-6 col-lg-4">
       <img class="mb-3" width="170" height="170" src="<?php 
         the_field('section_3_image_' . ($i+1)) ?>"
           alt="<?php the_field('section_3_image_' . ($i+1) . '_alt') ?>">
        <h3 style="min-height: 150px"><?php the_field('text_one', false, false) ?></h3>
       <p class="pb-5">
          <a href="<?php the_field('link_' . ($i+1)); ?>"
           title="<?php the_field('title_' . ($i+1)); ?>"
           class="btn btn-lg btn-secondary">
            <?php the_field('link'); ?>
        </a>
    </p>
 </div>
```